# Opencart hide default text if no special offers available

Tags: customization, opencart, default

My question is similar to [OpenCart Hide special offers title if no special offers available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536473/opencart-hide-special-offers-title-if-no-special-offers-available).

I want to remove the default text, "There are no special offer products to list." that displays when there are no specials offered.

I do not know the file from which I could find and remove this.

I'd be grateful for some help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The text you are looking for is in the following language file:

`catalog/language/english/product/special.php`

You can either remove the text between the single quotes, so the `$_['text_empty']` variable would be the following:

`$_['text_empty']        = '';`

... or as a better solution, you could just disable displaying it in your theme. Search for the following file:

`catalog/view/theme/YOUR_THEME_NAME/template/product/special.tpl`

... and then remove the following string from it:

`<?php echo $text_empty; ?>`

An even better way would be using a vQmod script, but you mentioned in your question, that you'd like to remove it from the file, so I would skip this part.